# How to check the values from mysql database?

Tags: android, database

I am making a word connect game in which the user has to connect the letters one by one and make a word. I have made sqldatabase in which there are two columns with ID and words with 40 records. I want suggestions on how to check the answer from the database after the user has pressed all the buttons.

There are four buttons in which button1 has value "S", button2 has value "C", button3 has value "A", and button 4 has value "M". Now, if the user makes the word "SCAM" after the four buttons are pressed then is should check from the database. If the word is correct then it should say that "CORRECT ANSWER", otherwise the user has to try again. Help me with these.

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about `MySQL` database, so you are using client-server architecture, so When a user Pressed four button and made "SCAM" you need to send this data to the server, then you need to check your values with the `MySQL` database...

But I think it's a little bad idea, to check the result in the server-side
because the user cannot play offline, and every time the player should wait for you to connect to the server, check the response and show a result. but the whole game should be fast.

It would be so better to use `SQLITE` instead of `MYSQL`. so you can do all of your operations in offline mode.

There are multiple ways for doing this, you can download all game contents from your server on the first load and then store it on `SQLITE`

But if you want to make your game completely offline, you can create an `SQLITE` file using [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/) or some applications like that. fill the database with your game data, then place the `SQLITE` file in your android application's `assets` folder.

after first open, you can easily copy this file to the device and read/write data from/to this database

Maybe this library help's you to copy the database

[Android-Copy-Database](https://github.com/shanraisshan/Android-Copy-Database)

or this page

[Ship an Android app with a pre-populated database](https://medium.com/@johann.pardanaud/ship-an-android-app-with-a-pre-populated-database-cd2b3aa3311f)

Comment: Ok.Thank u for that. And how can I do that using sqlite database.

Comment: How do I check from the database that the word is correct or not?

Comment: you need to learn SQL commands, as instance, you can check the word with database with this query: `SELECT * FROM WORDS WHERE WORD = 'SCAM'`